# Move the Worksheet Tabs in Excel 2010 to the top of the Window

Tags: microsoft-excel, tabs, microsoft-excel-2010

It is standard that when you open MS Excel, the tabs for each worksheet appear along the bottom of the window (as "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", etc).

I would prefer **those tabs to be on top of the spreadsheet** rather than the bottom (i.e. just below the ribbon and formula bar). Is it possible? I am using MS Excel 2010.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

(SO requires 30+ characters per answer, so here they are.)

Comment: That's unfortunate... oh well.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: Are you asking Derek why he wants to or me why you can't?

Comment: Im asking why you can't do this. Why is the answer no?

Comment: I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition if it helps anyone:
The only option I found was the ability to turn the sheet tabs **completely off** and for *this workbook only*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's an add-in that does this: [XL sheetpicker](http://www.add-in-world.com/katalog/xl-sheetpicker/) Unfortunately, the website is only provided in German, but I'm sure the add-in will also work on non-German systems. They also offer a pro version for 1.5€ [here](http://www.add-in-world.com/katalog/xl-sheetpicker-pro/).